# docker compose not finding my files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Docker is telling me it cant find the specified file.  Is my context wrong?  My folder structure is as follows.

```
root
  - docker
    - docker-compose-service.yml
  - service
    - DockerFile
  Nuget.config
```

Inside my docker-compose-service.yml file I have

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ../service/DockerFile
```

I run from the root folder the following command

```
docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose-service.yml up --build
```

It can find the Dockerfile as it runs the code but fails on a line inside the dockerFile which is

```
COPY NuGet.config .
```

The error is

```
failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder408021827/NuGet.config: no such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I played around with the context and dockerFile location but then it couldn't find the DockerFile

---

Hmm so if I run the command from the docker folder and change the docker-compose-service.yml file to be

```
context: ../
dockerfile: service/DockerFile
```

That seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, from what I can see in projects, context's are build in a different way. You should reorganize your project like this:

```
root
  - docker-compose.yml
  - service
    - Dockerfile
    - Nuget.config
```

The `build` in the compose file would look like this afterwards:

```
build: ./service
```

And you run it like:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Answer (score 2):

The path specified in your docker file sets the context as the parent folder of the compose file.
In order to make it work, you need to either:

1. Change the context to `.`
2. Change the path to `NuGet.config` to also contain the current folder name: `root/NuGet.config`

I would recommend the first approach as from your question I don't see any reason you would want to refer to the parent folder.